# CodeIngniter contando linhas e exibindo na View?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc

Quero contar e exibir um campo do banco de dados.

**Banco de Dados:** `nbkg`

**Tabela:** `chamados`

`Model:` `chamados_model.php`

```
<?php

class dashboard_model extends CI_Model{

    public function lista($chamados)
    {

    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM chamados');

    echo $query->num_rows();       

    }

}
```

`Controller:` `Dashboard.php`

```
    <?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('dashboard.php');
        $this->load->model("dashboard_model");
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }
}
```

`View:` `dashboard.php`

```
<?php echo $query ?>
```

***Erro:*** não encontra a variável `Query`:

> A PHP Error was encountered> 
>   Severity: Notice> 
>   Message: Undefined variable: query> 
>   Filename: views/dashboard.php
>
> Line Number: 1
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nbkg/application/views/dashboard.php
>   Line: 1 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nbkg/application/controllers/Dashboard.php
>   Line: 8 Function: view
>
> File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nbkg/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model

```
<?php
class dashboard_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function lista()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM chamados');
        # se vai usar o valor em outro lugar, então pense que o mesmo será um retorno
        return (int) $query->num_rows();       
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php 
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        # cria instancia da library
        $this->load->library('database');

        # cria instancia do helper
        $this->load->helper('url');
    } 


    public function index()
    {
        # cria instancia do model
        $this->load->model("dashboard_model");

        # executa sua função dentro da model e recupera o valor
        $lista = $this->dashboard_model->lista();

        # chama a view (não precisa do .php)
        # o array dentro da função da view, passa as chaves para a view e os transforma em variaveis (extract)
        $this->load->view('dashboard', 
            array(
                 'query' => $lista
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: agora esta dando erro 


An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: Database

Comment: Retire `$this->load->library('database');` e adicione `'database' ` no `array` do arquivo `application/config/autoload.php` na chave `$autoload['libraries']`.

Comment: E na view chamo $lista . 

correto?

Comment: Não, mantenha intacto, caso tenha seguido meu exemplo. A variável se chama `$query` (veja a chave do `array` que ele transforma em variáveis).

Comment: Done!! Obrigado